# JAudioTagger Android - Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making an ID3 tag editor for Android as a way of doing something practical with my java basics. I have the JAudioTagger library added to the Eclipse projects build path, and Eclipse is seeing it correctly. My application compiles and runs, but once I've chosen an MP3 to edit, the application force closes as it tries to load tag information.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Am I initializing the library wrong, or is it something to do with an improper build path?

EditActivity.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioHeader;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotReadException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.InvalidAudioFrameException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.ReadOnlyFileException;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.FieldKey;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.Tag;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.TagException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class EditActivity extends Activity
{
    AudioFile audioFile = null;
    Tag audioTag = null;
    AudioHeader audioHeader = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        // Get our target file from the passed intent's extras
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String SONG_DATA = i.getStringExtra("SONG_DATA");
        File targetFile = new File(SONG_DATA);

        try
        {
            // Open File
            audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(targetFile);
            audioTag = audioFile.getTag();
            audioHeader = audioFile.getAudioHeader();

            // set its info to fields
            EditText editTrackNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_trackNum);
            EditText editTrackNumTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_trackNumTotal);
            EditText editDiscNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_discNum);
            EditText editDiscNumTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_discNumTotal);
            EditText editArtist = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_artist);
            EditText editAlbum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_album);
            EditText editGenre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_genre);

            if (audioTag != null)
            {
                editTrackNum.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK));
                editTrackNumTotal.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK_TOTAL));
                editDiscNum.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.DISC_NO));
                editDiscNumTotal.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.DISC_TOTAL));
            editArtist.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST));
                editAlbum.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM));
                editGenre.setText(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.GENRE));

                // get cover art
                ImageView editImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_image);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.COVER_ART));
                editImage.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
    }
    catch (CannotReadException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TagException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ReadOnlyFileException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
E/dalvikvm(27537): Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer', referenced from method org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.readV2Tag
W/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1179 (Lsun/nio/ch/DirectBuffer;) in Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3/MP3File;
D/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x006f
E/dalvikvm(27537): Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer', referenced from method org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.readV2Tag
W/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1179 (Lsun/nio/ch/DirectBuffer;) in Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3/MP3File;
D/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00af
D/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: dead code 0x0071-0077 in Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3/MP3File;.readV2Tag (Ljava/io/File;II)V
D/dalvikvm(27537): VFY: dead code 0x00b1-00b7 in Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3/MP3File;.readV2Tag (Ljava/io/File;II)V
D/AndroidRuntime(27537): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(27537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401ef560)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27537): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.readV2Tag(MP3File.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.<init>(MP3File.java:466)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3FileReader.read(MP3FileReader.java:39)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.readFile(AudioFileIO.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO.read(AudioFileIO.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at com.eccproductions.audioid.EditActivity.onCreate(EditActivity.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime(27537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I got exactly same error while updated to 2.2.0 version of this library. Made rollback to 2.0.4

Comment: To be concrete -- to jaudiotagger-2.0.4-20111207.115108-15.jar. Even 2.0.4-....-16 version don't work on android.

It seems, that android support it finally dropped in JAudioTagger.

Anyway, if You're interested -- You can download working for android jar from my server (since it was removed from official release page) -- http://cleer.cc.trousev.pro/artifacts/core/jaudiotagger-2.0.4-20111207.115108-15.jar

Comment: I actually didn't think of doing a rollback... *facepalm*
Thanks Arenim.

Comment: I did not too. I've just UPGRADED and faced it :)

Comment: Thank you for the jar file, Arenim!

Comment: @Arenim, Do you still have this file? Link not working anymore

Comment: Ooops, yep, something destroyed. I'll try to search and re-upload =))